# get the content of a .txt file from S3 and display its content in HTML with lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a question. I have connected my S3 to Lambda via AWS. I need to get the content of a .txt hosted on my S3 and display that content in HTML.Each time a file is created in S3, the content of the file must be displayed via HTML in Lambda.
That is, if the .txt has "Hello" written in it, I need to display in HTML "Hello".
How can I achieve this? So far, this is what I have

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        str_response = ""
        for key in response:
            
            str_response = str_response + "\t" + key + ":" + str(response[key]) + "\n"
        print("Full response from S3: \n"+  str_response+"\n CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

I have searched and I found this

```
bucket.put_object(Key='index.html', Body=data, ContentType='text/html')
```

I don't know where it goes or how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Displaied  where? Can you provide more details on exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.I have to host a .txt file in S3. This event triggers a function in Lambda. Lambda should take the content of that .txt and display it in a very simple web page, with just the HTML structure.
If in the .txt file is written "Hello world", it should display that "Hello world" in a web page.

Comment: lambda itself is completely headless. It can't display it anywhere.

You could, I suppose, have the lambda mutate the text file then save it as an html file in a public S3 bucket as long as that page is completely static

Comment: @lynkfox I understand. What function allows me to do that? Thank you very much !

Comment: there isn't one, not built in at least - you might be able to find some library that lets to do so, but you'd probably have to write a custom parser. If the .txt file is already formated in an html style, you can just change the extension and re upload it to the s3 bucket as a .html I suppose. If its index.html and your s3 bucket is set to public for a static page it should be able to be shown in some manner.

i suppose this is an XY problem - what is your use case here?